# Use yocto image output as file on another yocto image

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I have yocto recipe, which builds raspberry pi image. Lets call it *main image*. It's output is *main-image.wic.bz2* file. I would like to build another RPi image, used for recovery from USB flash. Lets call it *recovery image*. I know, how to achieve boot of this image from USB flash, but now I need to somehow get *main-image.wic.bz2* as file in recovery image. I'm still pretty new in yocto, so I would like to know, what is best way to achieve this.
Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have found it. It's actually pretty easy, there is ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE} variable, which points to *build/tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi4*. So there is my solution.

```
SUMMARY = "Recovery data package"
DESCRIPTION = ""
HOMEPAGE = ""
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

EXTRA_IMAGEDEPENDS = "main-image"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/usr/static
    install ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/main-image-raspberrypi4.wic.bz2 ${D}/usr/static
}

FILES:${PN} += "/usr/static"
```